# Flutter onPressed - Difference between using a function or make a direct call

Tags: flutter, dart, tapjoy

I am playing with Tapjoy's offerwall, I just don't know why this works:

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("request content for Placement 001"),
            onPressed: myPlacement.requestContent,
          ),
```

And then this doesn't:

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("request content for Placement 001"),
            onPressed: testFunction,
),

testFunction(){
    myPlacement.requestContent;
}
```

As you can see it's the same code but instead of calling directly I use a function...

requestContent returns a Future. This function internally makes a http request that I can see log in the console for the first option. The second one nothing happens..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code will work

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("request content for Placement 001"),
            onPressed: testFunction, ),

testFunction(){
    myPlacement.requestContent(); 
}
```

Use the bracket after `myPlacement.requestContent` inside the `testFunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("request content for Placement 001"),
            onPressed: testFunction(),
),

testFunction(){
    myPlacement.requestContent;
}
```

use bracket for the testFunction

Comment: Yes! I was reading and found that is not the same to call a function with or without brackets. Without brackets you are not calling the funcion, you are referencing it. Am I right?

Comment: Actually, the trick was putting brackets inside de function:  myPlacement.requestContent();

Comment: did it worked for you